# Http Basic Auth in Slim V2

Tags: php, api, slim

I've a problem using, under a Slim installation, the HTTP Basic Authentication.

I've to create an API that call a class method only if the http call is authenticated.

This is my markup:

```
<?php
$httpAuth = function () use ($app) {
    $app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication(array(
    "path" => "/api/generateScratch",
    "realm" => "Protected",
    "users" => array(
        "root" => "t00r",
        "user" => "passw0rd"
    ))));
};

$app->get('/api/generateScratch', $httpAuth, function() use($app,$db) {
    $params =  $app->request->getBody() ;
    if(!empty($params)){
        print $params;
        require_once ('classes/codes/codes.php');
        $codes = new Codes($db, 1);
        $res = $codes->assign($params);
    }
});
?>
```

How can I complete my api? I don't know how to make an http authenticated call.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are facing?

Comment: Hi Mike, the problem is that nothing works :) You see my code, when i go to /api/generateScratch i receive an "Type: ErrorException
Code: 4096
Message: Argument 1 passed to Slim\Slim::add() must be an instance of Slim\Middleware, instance of Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication given"

Comment: You should update your question to include the actual problem and the error message.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth/blob/1.x/README.md) install the Slim 2 version of the middleware.

```
$ composer require tuupola/slim-basic-auth:^1.0
```

Then you can do the following.

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "path" => "/api/generateScratch",
    "realm" => "Protected",
    "users" => [
        "root" => "t00r",
        "someone" => "passw0rd"
    ]
]));

$app->get('/api/generateScratch', function() use ($app, $db) {
    /* Here be dragons... */
});
```

If you want all your API routes to be authenticated do this instead.

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "path" => "/api",
    "realm" => "Protected",
    "users" => [
        "root" => "t00r",
        "someone" => "passw0rd"
    ]
]));
```

Comment: Mika remember that i'm using Slim V2, not V3...if i write "$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\HttpBasicAuthentication([
    "path" => "/api/generateScratch",
    "realm" => "Protected",
    "users" => [
        "root" => "t00r",
        "someone" => "passw0rd"
    ]
])); "  i receive the error..

Comment: My example and link to documentation is for Slim v2. Are you sure you are using correct version of the plugin from Slim v2? To me it sounds like you are trying to use Slim 3 plugin in Slim 2 application.

Comment: where can i get plugin for v2?

Comment: Instructions are in the documentation: https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth/blob/1.x/README.md

Answer (score 0):

Mika,

i add some info:

- i'm using SLim v2
- i'm using a previous slim installation so i can't use $app->run  or  $app = new \Slim\Slim();  because these instruction are in the project main index.php